# 500 server error due to upgrading to PHP 5.6, .htaccess rewrite loop possibly?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have upgraded PHP from 5.5 to 5.6, and all of a sudden I am having 500 server error for my websites that use url rewrite. I talked to webhost and they said my .htaccess causes rewrite loop. Its strange though, since I've had the same .htaccess file and it never changed. Below is the code in my .htaccess file, anyone know where I get it wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^get/([0-9]+).gif$ /click/siggy/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following Rule is causing an Infinite loop/500 error on your server as the target path is rewriting to itself :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

The rule above excludes **js,css,gif..** and rewrites any other files to /index.php including **/index.php => /index.php** .
To fix this,
You have to exclude the target path /index.php using a negitive Rewrite cond :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```